# Passing Array for Oracle Store Procedure with LabVIEW

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, labview

I am trying to develop one LabVIEW vi that is able to transfer some parameters for an Oracle store procedure using the LabVIEW Database Connectivity Toolkit. I had been researching and following examples from Toolkit Documentation (chapter7) https://download.ni.com/support/manuals/371525a.pdf , yet I have not been able to pass an array as parameter. At the very end of chapter, it states "The stored procedure examples shown in this section are specifically written for SQL Server. Oracle uses PL/SQL to create stored procedures. Although the syntax for PL/SQL is different, you still can create and run stored procedures for Oracle using the Database Connectivity Toolkit." but I wonder if someone has been able to succeed passing an Array for Oracle Store Procedure or if a different approach should be used.

This because manual states we are able to do it but I encounter an error when using arrays (passing parameter one by one is functionable yet not a solution for my particular case), and Toolkit also mentions we should use binary instead of arrays, which confuse me as manual examples do not use binary data types for array conversion.[data-types conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqLyM.png)

Comment: Show a description of the Oracle procedure, as well as how you are trying to pass an array to this procedure?

Comment: It might be easier to build the SQL query yourself rather than relying on NI's parametric query VI.